# Rewrite a formula in terms of exponential to the power of logarithm

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation

I would like to rewrite the following formula, `f(x)`.

how can I rewrite the `f(x)`

$$ f(x) = \frac{(1+2B)}{2A\sqrt{B^2+(1+2B)\frac{x}{A}}}$$

as $$\exp^{\log(f(x)}$$

Comment: Please clarify what you want; $f(x)$ doesn't seem to have either exponents or logarithms.

Comment: @vadmin I edited my question as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here you go:

$$ f(x) =e^{\ln f(x) } = e^{\ln \frac{(1+2B)}{2A\sqrt{B^2+(1+2B)\frac{x}{A}}}} = e^{(\ln 1+2b) - \ln 2A - \ln \sqrt{B^2+(1+2B)\frac{x}{A}}}$$